# Snowflake Alter Script not executing in Databricks

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-databricks

I am trying to execute the snowflake alter script in Databricks using below statement I am getting the syntax error same script is running in snowflake.

```
spark.read.format("snowflake").options(**options)\
  .option("query", "ALTER TABLE tablename SET CHANGE_TRACKING = TRUE").load()
```

getting syntax error, what mistake I am doing here.

Comment: Hi, Could you please add the text of the error? It might have some clues here.

Comment: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 15 unexpected 'ALTER'.
syntax error line 1 at position 44 unexpected 'SET'  like this.

Comment: If you want to run raw SQL why not using then `spark.sql("ALTER TABLE tablename SET CHANGE_TRACKING = TRUE")` ?

Comment: I tried it not working, but it is not raw sql it is snowflake alter script I have to run it from Databricks.

Answer (score 2):

Highly likely you are facing this error because of the `read` method. Under the hood it wraps your ALTER query as a select, which makes the entire query is not correct. For [DDL and DML statements](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use#executing-ddl-dml-sql-statements) you should use the `Utils` class instead:

```
Utils.runQuery(sfOptions, "ALTER TABLE tablename SET CHANGE_TRACKING = TRUE")
```